# Tokina AT-X 120 Pro DX AF 11-20mm f/2.8 vs Tokina AT-X 11-20mm f/2.8 Pro DX

Tags: lens, equipment-identification, tokina

for my Canon 80D am looking for a wide angle fast lens. Am considering the Tokina 11-20mm f/2.8.
Am confused though as I have found online two different names with apparently the same specifications.

**Tokina AT-X 11-20mm f/2.8 Pro DX**
This is the most commonly found and reviewed, with a price going from 500+ EUR up.
The Tokina official site has this lens (discontinued in 2020 and replaced by the CF version for APS-C cameras)
Specifications:
Focal Length    11-20mm
Maximum Aperture    2.8
Minimum Aperture    22
Construction E/G    11E / 12G
Coatings    Advanced Multi-layer
Angle of View    104.34 - 72.42°
Minimum Focus Distance    0.9 ft (0.28 m)
Macro Ratio    1:8.62
Focusing Mode    AF
Zooming System    Rotating
Aperture Blades    9
SD Glass    3 elements
Filter Size    82mm
Filter Thread   0.5
Maximum Outer Diameter    3.5 in (89mm)
Lens Width    3.5 in (89mm)
Lens Length    3.6 in (92mm)
Weight    1.2 lbs (560g)
Accessories    Hood, Lens Hood, BH-821
Mounts    Canon, Nikon

**Tokina AT-X 120 Pro DX AF 11-20mm f/2.8**
I have found this naming of the product only in three shops, with a price around 360 EUR
The Tokina website apparently does not list this.
Specifications:

- P-MO & Glass-Molded Aspherical Elements
- Local Length: 11-20mm
- Maximum Aperture: 2.8
- Minimum Aperture: 22
- Construction E/G: 11E / 12G
- Coatings: Advanced Multi-layer
- Angle of View: 104.34 - 72.42°
- Minimum Focus Distance: 0.9 ft (0.28 m)
- Macro Ratio: 1:8.62
- Filter Size: 82mm
  These are all the specifications available

I can't find online any further information regarding the second lens. The price seems the only differentiating element. Is the second one an older version? In what is it different from the Tokina AT-X 11-20mm f/2.8 Pro DX?

EDIT:
I added the image of the lens from the shop.
[image: Tokina 11-20]

Comment: Are you sure they're not the same lens?  It's common to reorder the feature designations when referring to lenses.  Do you have the model numbers?

Comment: @xiota I don't understand if they are the same lens or not. The price difference makes me think there is something different. No, I don't have model numbers. I'm not sure if I can add the link of the seller as it is an ecommerce site. My intent is not of promoting them.

Comment: @DuncanDrake: Just one note of caution: there is an older Tokina 11-16 f/2.8, so it may be worth double checking that the less expensive one you're seeing really is the 11-20. This could also explain how the lower price came about--they may have gotten the upgraded 11-20, and marked it with their existing price for the 11-16.

Comment: @JerryCoffin thank you. I added the image of the lens from the shop. Seems a 11-20 alright. Has a 'SD' marking which is not in the official name of the lens. Confusing. -.-

Comment: They are for different markets or Tokina changed the name at some point. Have you called THK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There the same lens with the name written differently. Most times this is a simple mistake when transcribing a name from the manufacturer. Lens names are complex and indeed look quite similar and honestly, Tokina has one of the more complicated schemes which they use inconsistently.

As I have a site about digital cameras and lenses, Tokina sends me this information with each new lens. There were only two 11-20mm lenses produced for Canon EF mount and theose are the AT-X 11-20mm F/2.8 PRO DX and ATX-I 11-20mm F/2.8 CF. These lenses have a different finish but otherwise almost identical. You can [compare these lenses side-by-side here](https://www.neocamera.com/lens_compare.php?model%5B%5D=930&model%5B%5D=1620&compare=) on my site Neocamera.

ATX-120 and AT-X 11-20mm F/2.8 PRO DX refers to the same lens. The former is the model number and the latter is the model name. The second name you found is a combination of both, so looks like a data entry issue and not a different lenses.

Interestingly, you can save a lot of money by buying incorrectly named products! Stores respond to low sales by lowering prices and if something is incorrectly named, then people don't find it, so there are fewer buyers. I vaguely remember someone make a ton of money from buying incorrectly listed designer clothing and selling them back with the correct name!

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful! Will check your site

Comment: i added the image of the lens from the shop. Maybe they did make a mistake with the prices.

Comment: Notice that it matches with the press image sent by Tokina? Spec page is here shows a larger image than the comparison view: https://www.neocamera.com/lens/tokina/at-x_11-20mm_f2.8_pro_dx/canon - Looks identical to the image you added

Comment: It looks indeed the same. Thank you!